# EKCalendar title in iOS12 is blank

Tags: iphone, swift, ios12

In iOS 12 I'm trying to list the calendars. I can print the calendar ids, but the titles are all blank. What am I doing wrong?

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let status = EKEventStore.authorizationStatus(for: EKEntityType.event)

        switch (status) {
        case EKAuthorizationStatus.notDetermined:
            EKEventStore().requestAccess(to: .event, completion: {
                (granted: Bool, error: Error?) in

                if granted != true {
                    print("Access not granted")
                }
            })
        case EKAuthorizationStatus.authorized:
            print("Access granted")
        case EKAuthorizationStatus.restricted, EKAuthorizationStatus.denied:
            print("Access restricted or denied")
        }

        print("Calendars:")
        for c in EKEventStore().calendars(for: EKEntityType.event) {
            print("    \(c.calendarIdentifier):\(c.title)")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why, but this code shows event titles in iOS 12 Simulator.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    let status = EKEventStore.authorizationStatus(for: EKEntityType.event)
    let eventStore = EKEventStore() //<-
    switch (status) {
    case EKAuthorizationStatus.notDetermined:
        eventStore.requestAccess(to: .event, completion: {
            (granted: Bool, error: Error?) in

            if granted != true {
                print("Access not granted")
            }
        })
    case EKAuthorizationStatus.authorized:
        print("Access granted")
    case EKAuthorizationStatus.restricted, EKAuthorizationStatus.denied:
        print("Access restricted or denied")
    }

    print("Calendars:")
    for c in eventStore.calendars(for: EKEntityType.event) {
        print("    \(c.calendarIdentifier):\(c.title)",c)
    }
}
```

Maybe, you need to keep strong reference to the instance of `EKEventStore` while accessing `EKCalendar` properties.

Comment: i am facing calender sync issues in iOS 12

Comment: @GvSharma, you should better start a new thread of your own issue, if you cannot find an answer in SO. Syncing is completely different thing than this issue.

Comment: This took me a long time but it worked, even on iOS 13 beta